# How to extend styles in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, styles

I have some base class component Base and child components called Child1 and Child2. I have some base styles in Base component also but I want to overwrite it in children. It does not work as I expect because one of child component's styles overwrites another child styles.

Base component:

```
<template>
<div class="communicate">
   Blabla
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component ({})
export default class Base extends Vue {}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
//not scoped
.communicate {
   color: red;
}
</style>
```

Child 1 component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Base from './Base.vue';

@Component ({})
export default class Child1 extends Base {}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.communicate {
   color: blue;
}
</style>
```

and similar Child2 component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Base from './Base.vue';

@Component ({})
export default class Child2 extends Base {}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.communicate {
   color: green;
}
</style>
```

Color is always blue, event in Child2 component.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible currently. Please see the following issue for `vue-loader`: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1003

As a workaround, you can use `sass` preprocessor, for example, in order to reuse styles for child components.